# My PC is intermittently locking up. The screen goes black (no light). The keyboard is lit and nothing will react

Tags: kubuntu

This is a new Kubuntu install.  I cannot reproduce this problem.  It happens intermittently.

The screen will go black.  As in the backlight will turn off.  And none of the buttons seem to react.  Not even the power button (which is set to power down the machine).

The keyboard backlight (which is on when this happens) will remain lit.

I have to hard reboot to get the system back.

**HERE is the wierd thing**
This happens at least once per day (going on 4 days).
The system will always reopen the exact same things I was working on from the very first time it happened.
E.G.:

- Chapter 2 of the KDE Help Center
- Quick Settings -- System Settings
- Firefox (blank)

Here is the Laptop's info:
Kubuntu Version 22.10

```
txtechnician-hp-kubuntu
    description: Notebook
    product: HP Beats 15 Notebook PC (G6R14UA#ABA)
    vendor: Hewlett-Packard
    version: 097A100000403D00000620180
    serial: 5CD4263953
    width: 64 bits
    capabilities: smbios-2.8 dmi-2.8 smp vsyscall32
    configuration: boot=normal chassis=notebook family=103C_5335KV G=N L=CON B=HP S=PAV sku=G6R14UA#ABA uuid=34444335-3632-3933-3533-6cc21766a394
  *-core
       description: Motherboard
       product: 22A8
       vendor: Hewlett-Packard
       physical id: 0
       version: 90.10
       serial: PEKFC008J6T7UA
       slot: Base Board Chassis Location
     *-firmware
          description: BIOS
          vendor: American Megatrends Inc.
          physical id: 0
          version: F.10
          date: 06/09/2014
          size: 64KiB
          capacity: 4MiB
          capabilities: pci upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect edd int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer acpi usb smartbattery biosbootspecification netboot uefi
     *-cache:0
          description: L1 cache
          physical id: d
          slot: L1 CACHE
          size: 192KiB
          capacity: 192KiB
          clock: 1GHz (1.0ns)
          capabilities: pipeline-burst internal write-back unified
          configuration: level=1
     *-cache:1
          description: L2 cache
          physical id: e
          slot: L2 CACHE
          size: 4MiB
          capacity: 4MiB
          clock: 1GHz (1.0ns)
          capabilities: pipeline-burst internal write-back unified
          configuration: level=2
     *-memory
          description: System Memory
          physical id: 16
          slot: System board or motherboard
          size: 8GiB
          capabilities: ecc
          configuration: errordetection=multi-bit-ecc
        *-bank:0
             description: SODIMM [empty]
             product: A1_PartNum0
             vendor: A1_Manufacturer0
             physical id: 0
             serial: A1_SerialNum0
             slot: Bottom-Slot 1(left)
             width: 64 bits
        *-bank:1
             description: SODIMM DDR3 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 1600 MHz (0.6 ns)
             product: EBJ81UG8EFU0-GN-F
             vendor: Elpida
             physical id: 1
             serial: 760109EE
             slot: Bottom-Slot 2(right)
             size: 8GiB
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 1600MHz (0.6ns)
     *-cpu
          description: CPU
          product: AMD A8-5545M APU with Radeon(tm) HD Graphics
          vendor: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD]
          physical id: 20
          bus info: cpu@0
          version: 21.19.1
          slot: P0
          size: 1097MHz
          capacity: 1700MHz
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 100MHz
          capabilities: lm fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht syscall nx mmxext fxsr_opt pdpe1gb rdtscp x86-64 constant_tsc rep_good nopl nonstop_tsc cpuid extd_apicid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq monitor ssse3 fma cx16 sse4_1 sse4_2 popcnt aes xsave avx f16c lahf_lm cmp_legacy svm extapic cr8_legacy abm sse4a misalignsse 3dnowprefetch osvw ibs xop skinit wdt lwp fma4 tce nodeid_msr tbm topoext perfctr_core perfctr_nb cpb hw_pstate ssbd vmmcall bmi1 arat npt lbrv svm_lock nrip_save tsc_scale vmcb_clean flushbyasid decodeassists pausefilter pfthreshold cpufreq
          configuration: cores=4 enabledcores=4 microcode=100667673 threads=4
     *-pci:0
          description: Host bridge
          product: Family 15h (Models 10h-1fh) Processor Root Complex
          vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
          physical id: 100
          bus info: pci@0000:00:00.0
          version: 00
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 66MHz
        *-display
             description: VGA compatible controller
             product: Richland [Radeon HD 8510G]
             vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
             physical id: 1
             bus info: pci@0000:00:01.0
             logical name: /dev/fb0
             version: 00
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom fb
             configuration: depth=32 driver=radeon latency=0 resolution=1366,768
             resources: irq:40 memory:d0000000-dfffffff ioport:f000(size=256) memory:feb00000-feb3ffff memory:c0000-dffff
        *-multimedia:0
             description: Audio device
             product: Trinity HDMI Audio Controller
             vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
             physical id: 1.1
             bus info: pci@0000:00:01.1
             version: 00
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm pciexpress msi bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
             resources: irq:41 memory:feb44000-feb47fff
        *-pci:0
             description: PCI bridge
             product: Family 15h (Models 10h-1fh) Processor Root Port
             vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
             physical id: 4
             bus info: pci@0000:00:04.0
             version: 00
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pm pciexpress msi ht normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:24 ioport:e000(size=4096) memory:fea00000-feafffff
           *-network
                description: Wireless interface
                product: RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
                vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
                logical name: wlo1
                version: 00
                serial: 90:48:9a:e1:7b:b1
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
                configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8723be driverversion=5.19.0-35-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.50.219 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
                resources: irq:16 ioport:e000(size=256) memory:fea00000-fea03fff
        *-pci:1
             description: PCI bridge
             product: Family 15h (Models 10h-1fh) Processor Root Port
             vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
             physical id: 5
             bus info: pci@0000:00:05.0
             version: 00
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pm pciexpress msi ht normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:25 ioport:d000(size=4096) memory:fe900000-fe9fffff
           *-network
                description: Ethernet interface
                product: RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
                vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
                logical name: eno1
                version: 07
                serial: 6c:c2:17:66:a3:94
                capacity: 100Mbit/s
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
                configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=5.19.0-35-generic firmware=rtl8106e-1_0.0.1 06/29/12 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
                resources: irq:17 ioport:d000(size=256) memory:fe914000-fe914fff memory:fe910000-fe913fff memory:fe900000-fe90ffff
        *-pci:2
             description: PCI bridge
             product: Family 15h (Models 10h-1fh) Processor Root Port
             vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
             physical id: 6
             bus info: pci@0000:00:06.0
             version: 00
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pm pciexpress msi ht normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:26 memory:fe800000-fe8fffff
           *-generic
                description: MMC Host
                product: RTS5229 PCI Express Card Reader
                vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
                logical name: mmc0
                version: 01
                width: 32 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
                configuration: driver=rtsx_pci latency=0
                resources: irq:27 memory:fe800000-fe800fff
        *-usb:0
             description: USB controller
             product: FCH USB XHCI Controller
             vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
             physical id: 10
             bus info: pci@0000:00:10.0
             version: 09
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi msix pciexpress xhci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=xhci_hcd latency=0
             resources: irq:18 memory:feb4a000-feb4bfff
           *-usbhost:0
                product: xHCI Host Controller
                vendor: Linux 5.19.0-35-generic xhci-hcd
                physical id: 0
                bus info: usb@6
                logical name: usb6
                version: 5.19
                capabilities: usb-2.00
                configuration: driver=hub slots=2 speed=480Mbit/s
           *-usbhost:1
                product: xHCI Host Controller
                vendor: Linux 5.19.0-35-generic xhci-hcd
                physical id: 1
                bus info: usb@7
                logical name: usb7
                version: 5.19
                capabilities: usb-3.00
                configuration: driver=hub slots=2 speed=5000Mbit/s
        *-usb:1
             description: USB controller
             product: FCH USB XHCI Controller
             vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
             physical id: 10.1
             bus info: pci@0000:00:10.1
             version: 09
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi msix pciexpress xhci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=xhci_hcd latency=0
             resources: irq:17 memory:feb48000-feb49fff
           *-usbhost:0
                product: xHCI Host Controller
                vendor: Linux 5.19.0-35-generic xhci-hcd
                physical id: 0
                bus info: usb@8
                logical name: usb8
                version: 5.19
                capabilities: usb-2.00
                configuration: driver=hub slots=2 speed=480Mbit/s
           *-usbhost:1
                product: xHCI Host Controller
                vendor: Linux 5.19.0-35-generic xhci-hcd
                physical id: 1
                bus info: usb@9
                logical name: usb9
                version: 5.19
                capabilities: usb-3.00
                configuration: driver=hub slots=2 speed=5000Mbit/s
        *-sata
             description: SATA controller
             product: FCH SATA Controller [AHCI mode]
             vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
             physical id: 11
             bus info: pci@0000:00:11.0
             logical name: scsi0
             logical name: scsi1
             version: 40
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: sata msi ahci_1.0 bus_master cap_list emulated
             configuration: driver=ahci latency=32
             resources: irq:28 ioport:f190(size=8) ioport:f180(size=4) ioport:f170(size=8) ioport:f160(size=4) ioport:f150(size=16) memory:feb51000-feb517ff
           *-disk
                description: ATA Disk
                product: SPCC Solid State
                physical id: 0
                bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0
                logical name: /dev/sda
                version: Hf10
                serial: 30080945678
                size: 953GiB (1024GB)
                capabilities: gpt-1.00 partitioned partitioned:gpt
                configuration: ansiversion=5 guid=3aab7eef-332e-4f2f-a662-f80dc0e72fe4 logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=512
              *-volume:0 UNCLAIMED
                   description: Windows FAT volume
                   vendor: mkfs.fat
                   physical id: 1
                   bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,1
                   version: FAT32
                   serial: 61d2-2069
                   size: 510MiB
                   capacity: 511MiB
                   capabilities: boot fat initialized
                   configuration: FATs=2 filesystem=fat name=EFI System Partition
              *-volume:1
                   description: EXT4 volume
                   vendor: Linux
                   physical id: 2
                   bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,2
                   logical name: /dev/sda2
                   logical name: /
                   logical name: /var/snap/firefox/common/host-hunspell
                   version: 1.0
                   serial: 49fee6cb-42ca-429e-9f6d-3573e16799ad
                   size: 953GiB
                   capabilities: journaled extended_attributes large_files huge_files dir_nlink recover 64bit extents ext4 ext2 initialized
                   configuration: created=2023-03-16 12:54:36 filesystem=ext4 lastmountpoint=/ modified=2023-03-21 11:58:34 mount.fstype=ext4 mount.options=ro,noexec,noatime,errors=remount-ro mounted=2023-03-21 11:58:36 state=mounted
           *-cdrom
                description: DVD-RAM writer
                product: DVDRW  DU8A5SHL
                vendor: hp
                physical id: 1
                bus info: scsi@1:0.0.0
                logical name: /dev/cdrom
                logical name: /dev/sr0
                version: ZH63
                capabilities: removable audio cd-r cd-rw dvd dvd-r dvd-ram
                configuration: ansiversion=5 status=nodisc
        *-usb:2
             description: USB controller
             product: FCH USB OHCI Controller
             vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
             physical id: 12
             bus info: pci@0000:00:12.0
             version: 11
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: ohci bus_master
             configuration: driver=ohci-pci latency=32
             resources: irq:18 memory:feb50000-feb50fff
           *-usbhost
                product: OHCI PCI host controller
                vendor: Linux 5.19.0-35-generic ohci_hcd
                physical id: 1
                bus info: usb@3
                logical name: usb3
                version: 5.19
                capabilities: usb-1.10
                configuration: driver=hub slots=5 speed=12Mbit/s
              *-usb:0
                   description: Bluetooth wireless interface
                   product: Bluetooth Radio
                   vendor: Realtek
                   physical id: 3
                   bus info: usb@3:3
                   version: 2.00
                   serial: 00e04c000001
                   capabilities: bluetooth usb-2.10
                   configuration: driver=btusb maxpower=500mA speed=12Mbit/s
              *-usb:1
                   description: Human interface device
                   product: ELAN Touchscreen UNKNOWN
                   vendor: ELAN
                   physical id: 4
                   bus info: usb@3:4
                   logical name: input16
                   logical name: /dev/input/event7
                   logical name: /dev/input/mouse1
                   logical name: input17
                   logical name: /dev/input/event8
                   logical name: input18
                   logical name: /dev/input/event13
                   version: 11.23
                   capabilities: usb-2.00 usb
                   configuration: driver=usbhid maxpower=100mA speed=12Mbit/s
        *-usb:3
             description: USB controller
             product: FCH USB EHCI Controller
             vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
             physical id: 12.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:12.2
             version: 11
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: pm debug ehci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=ehci-pci latency=32
             resources: irq:17 memory:feb4f000-feb4f0ff
           *-usbhost
                product: EHCI Host Controller
                vendor: Linux 5.19.0-35-generic ehci_hcd
                physical id: 1
                bus info: usb@1
                logical name: usb1
                version: 5.19
                capabilities: usb-2.00
                configuration: driver=hub slots=5 speed=480Mbit/s
        *-usb:4
             description: USB controller
             product: FCH USB OHCI Controller
             vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
             physical id: 13
             bus info: pci@0000:00:13.0
             version: 11
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: ohci bus_master
             configuration: driver=ohci-pci latency=32
             resources: irq:18 memory:feb4e000-feb4efff
           *-usbhost
                product: OHCI PCI host controller
                vendor: Linux 5.19.0-35-generic ohci_hcd
                physical id: 1
                bus info: usb@4
                logical name: usb4
                version: 5.19
                capabilities: usb-1.10
                configuration: driver=hub slots=5 speed=12Mbit/s
        *-usb:5
             description: USB controller
             product: FCH USB EHCI Controller
             vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
             physical id: 13.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:13.2
             version: 11
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: pm debug ehci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=ehci-pci latency=32
             resources: irq:17 memory:feb4d000-feb4d0ff
           *-usbhost
                product: EHCI Host Controller
                vendor: Linux 5.19.0-35-generic ehci_hcd
                physical id: 1
                bus info: usb@2
                logical name: usb2
                version: 5.19
                capabilities: usb-2.00
                configuration: driver=hub slots=5 speed=480Mbit/s
              *-usb
                   description: Video
                   product: HP Truevision HD: HP Truevision
                   vendor: SuYin
                   physical id: 4
                   bus info: usb@2:4
                   logical name: input20
                   logical name: /dev/input/event14
                   version: 1.01
                   serial: HF1016-P82A-HM01-4-REV0101
                   capabilities: usb-2.00 usb
                   configuration: driver=uvcvideo maxpower=500mA speed=480Mbit/s
        *-serial
             description: SMBus
             product: FCH SMBus Controller
             vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
             physical id: 14
             bus info: pci@0000:00:14.0
             version: 16
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             configuration: driver=piix4_smbus latency=0
             resources: irq:0
        *-ide
             description: IDE interface
             product: FCH IDE Controller
             vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
             physical id: 14.1
             bus info: pci@0000:00:14.1
             version: 00
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: ide isa_compat_mode pci_native_mode bus_master
             configuration: driver=pata_atiixp latency=32
             resources: irq:17 ioport:1f0(size=8) ioport:3f6 ioport:170(size=8) ioport:376 ioport:f100(size=16)
        *-multimedia:1
             description: Audio device
             product: FCH Azalia Controller
             vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
             physical id: 14.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:14.2
             logical name: card1
             logical name: /dev/snd/controlC1
             logical name: /dev/snd/hwC1D0
             logical name: /dev/snd/pcmC1D0c
             logical name: /dev/snd/pcmC1D0p
             version: 01
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=32
             resources: irq:16 memory:feb40000-feb43fff
           *-input:0
                product: HD-Audio Generic Mic
                physical id: 0
                logical name: input14
                logical name: /dev/input/event6
           *-input:1
                product: HD-Audio Generic Headphone
                physical id: 1
                logical name: input15
                logical name: /dev/input/event12
        *-isa
             description: ISA bridge
             product: FCH LPC Bridge
             vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
             physical id: 14.3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
             version: 11
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: isa bus_master
             configuration: latency=0
           *-pnp00:00
                product: PnP device PNP0c01
                physical id: 0
                capabilities: pnp
                configuration: driver=system
           *-pnp00:01
                product: PnP device PNP0b00
                physical id: 1
                capabilities: pnp
                configuration: driver=rtc_cmos
           *-pnp00:02
                product: PnP device PNP0c02
                physical id: 2
                capabilities: pnp
                configuration: driver=system
           *-pnp00:03
                product: PnP device PNP0c02
                physical id: 3
                capabilities: pnp
                configuration: driver=system
           *-pnp00:04
                product: PnP device HPQ8001
                vendor: Hewlett-Packard Co.
                physical id: 4
                capabilities: pnp
                configuration: driver=i8042 kbd
           *-pnp00:05
                product: PnP device SYN1ebc
                vendor: Synaptics Inc
                physical id: 5
                capabilities: pnp
                configuration: driver=i8042 aux
           *-pnp00:06
                product: PnP device PNP0c02
                physical id: 6
                capabilities: pnp
                configuration: driver=system
           *-pnp00:07
                product: PnP device PNP0c02
                physical id: 7
                capabilities: pnp
                configuration: driver=system
        *-pci:3
             description: PCI bridge
             product: FCH PCI Bridge
             vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
             physical id: 14.4
             bus info: pci@0000:00:14.4
             version: 40
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: pci subtractive_decode bus_master
        *-usb:6
             description: USB controller
             product: FCH USB OHCI Controller
             vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
             physical id: 14.5
             bus info: pci@0000:00:14.5
             version: 11
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: ohci bus_master
             configuration: driver=ohci-pci latency=32
             resources: irq:18 memory:feb4c000-feb4cfff
           *-usbhost
                product: OHCI PCI host controller
                vendor: Linux 5.19.0-35-generic ohci_hcd
                physical id: 1
                bus info: usb@5
                logical name: usb5
                version: 5.19
                capabilities: usb-1.10
                configuration: driver=hub slots=2 speed=12Mbit/s
     *-pci:1
          description: Host bridge
          product: Family 15h (Models 10h-1fh) Processor Function 0
          vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
          physical id: 101
          bus info: pci@0000:00:18.0
          version: 00
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
     *-pci:2
          description: Host bridge
          product: Family 15h (Models 10h-1fh) Processor Function 1
          vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
          physical id: 102
          bus info: pci@0000:00:18.1
          version: 00
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
     *-pci:3
          description: Host bridge
          product: Family 15h (Models 10h-1fh) Processor Function 2
          vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
          physical id: 103
          bus info: pci@0000:00:18.2
          version: 00
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
     *-pci:4
          description: Host bridge
          product: Family 15h (Models 10h-1fh) Processor Function 3
          vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
          physical id: 104
          bus info: pci@0000:00:18.3
          version: 00
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
          configuration: driver=k10temp
          resources: irq:0
     *-pci:5
          description: Host bridge
          product: Family 15h (Models 10h-1fh) Processor Function 4
          vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
          physical id: 105
          bus info: pci@0000:00:18.4
          version: 00
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
     *-pci:6
          description: Host bridge
          product: Family 15h (Models 10h-1fh) Processor Function 5
          vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
          physical id: 106
          bus info: pci@0000:00:18.5
          version: 00
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
  *-battery
       product: VI04044
       vendor: 13-42
       physical id: 1
       slot: Primary
       capacity: 41440mWh
       configuration: voltage=14.8V
  *-input:0
       product: Power Button
       physical id: 2
       logical name: input0
       logical name: /dev/input/event0
       capabilities: platform
  *-input:1
       product: Lid Switch
       physical id: 3
       logical name: input1
       logical name: /dev/input/event1
       capabilities: platform
  *-input:2
       product: Wireless hotkeys
       physical id: 4
       logical name: input11
       logical name: /dev/input/event9
       capabilities: platform
  *-input:3
       product: ST LIS3LV02DL Accelerometer
       physical id: 5
       logical name: input12
       logical name: /dev/input/event10
       logical name: /dev/input/js0
       capabilities: platform
  *-input:4
       product: HP WMI hotkeys
       physical id: 6
       logical name: input13
       logical name: /dev/input/event11
       capabilities: platform
  *-input:5
       product: Power Button
       physical id: 7
       logical name: input2
       logical name: /dev/input/event2
       capabilities: platform
  *-input:6
       product: Air by AfterShokz (AVRCP)
       physical id: 8
       logical name: input21
       logical name: /dev/input/event15
       capabilities: bluetooth
  *-input:7
       product: AT Translated Set 2 keyboard
       physical id: 9
       logical name: input3
       logical name: /dev/input/event3
       logical name: input3::capslock
       logical name: input3::numlock
       logical name: input3::scrolllock
       capabilities: i8042
  *-input:8
       product: Video Bus
       physical id: a
       logical name: input5
       logical name: /dev/input/event4
       capabilities: platform
  *-input:9
       product: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad
       physical id: b
       logical name: input6
       logical name: /dev/input/event5
       logical name: /dev/input/mouse0
       capabilities: i8042
```

Where do I start in troubleshooting this problem?

Comment: The bit with the same apps opening every time is probably just KDE's session saving feature. As for the lockups, are you able to get to a terminal if you press Ctrl+Alt+F3 when the system locks up? If you can, then it's likely that it's Plasma or some GUI component that's freezing up. If not, then it's probably something deeper, like a kernel panic.

Comment: That keyboard combo did nothing.  System is totally non responsive